# Finding the equation of a rational function from a set of constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I need  to find the equation for the rational function $f$ with the following properties:

- Vertical asymptotes at $x = -4$ and  $x = -1$.
- $x$-intercepts at $(1, 0)$ and $(5, 0)$
- A $y$-intercept at $(0, 7)$

I have tried a trial and error approach to this question, but I haven't found one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical asymptotes in the graph of a rational function are indicated by the roots of the denominator, so your rational function might look like
$$ f(x) = \frac{\text{something}}{(x+4)(x+1)}\,.$$
Then the roots of the numerator indicate the $x$-intercepts, so maybe it's
$$ f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x-5)}{(x+4)(x+1)}\,.$$
But then you need the point $(0,7)$ to be a solution to your rational function, so just scale it by some $a$ that makes $(0,7)$ a solution:
$$ 7 = a\frac{(0-1)(0-5)}{(0+4)(0+1)}\,.$$
Solving this for $a$, we see that the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{28(x-1)(x-5)}{5(x+4)(x+1)}$$
satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Thanks that really helps =D

Comment: @Elijah yeah, sure thing. And welcome to MathSE. Please be sure to upvote answers to your question that you find helpful, and accept your favorite answer. And next time you post a question, you may want to add more context to it, like what exactly about the question is causing you problems: users of this site don't much like questions that read like homework questions

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will be sure to do that!